# Is it possible to update the cell value only to the specific maximum value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to update the cell value only to the specific maximum value? Here is query:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET premium_photos = premium_photos + 2 WHERE number = '1234'
```

I want to limit `premium_photos` (tinyint) value to max value of 4. Is it possible? For example if `premium_photos` current value is 2 and query is + 3, then after this query value will be 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `IF` function

```
UPDATE table_1 SET
   premium_photos = IF(premium_photos+2>4, 4, premium_photos+2)
WHERE number = '1234'
```

[IF() function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
UPDATE table_1 SET 
premium_photos = (CASE WHEN (premium_photos + 2) > 4 THEN 4 ELSE (premium_photos + 2) END) 
WHERE number = '1234'
```